# Latest Safari Browser issue with jPlayer

Tags: safari, jplayer

I am using jPlayer to play videos in one of my existing project. Everything works fine with Windows OS(in all browsers). Everything was also working fine in older Safari versions as well(in MAC OS). All of a sudden, in latest Safari version(in 13.1), videos are not playing and following error is generated in console panel.

I have also disable auto play option as well as per the latest guidelines. Any idea what could be wrong and how to detect issue?

[image]

Comment: Also experiencing this but with audio.  Looks like Apple changed something?

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced also some problems with the latest IOS. Updating the jplayer lib to latest 2.9 solved the issue.

Comment: Works for Safari 14.0.2 on MacOS 10.14.6. Latest release is at https://github.com/jplayer/jPlayer/tree/2.9.2